# How do I append user input? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a to-do list. When I open up the html file (I'm using Google Chrome), there seem to be two issues:

1. The button doesn't appear to be a button, as in it doesn't click.
2. When I press enter instead of trying to click the add button, the text just disappears.

But in both cases, neither method appends the user input. What do I need to fix?

I have the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
  });
});
```

```css
h2 {
  font-family: arial;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
#button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
.list {
  font-family: garamond;
  color: #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>To Do</h2>
<form name="checkListForm">
  <input type="text" name="checkListItem" />
</form>
<div id="button">Add!</div>
<br/>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: Probably button doesn't look as a button because it's a `div` on your code. Try using a `<button>` instead

Comment: The button works for me.

Comment: Why do you expect pressing enter to do anything? You don't have an event handler for that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Giving something the `id` of button does not make it a button. Maybe you should try: `<button id="button>Add!</button>`
2. When you press enter you are submitting the form, since you don't have any javascript intercepting the `onSubmit` event for the form it reloads the page.

If you want this action to happen when the user hits Enter, then you should move the button inside of the form and change the event to `$('form[name="checkListForm"]').on('submit', ...)`

Comment: Could you expand on how to make include the Enter event? What am I appending?

Comment: I see that it works in codepen, but when I copy and paste it to my files, it doesn't run append in either firefox or chrome ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I see a few problems here. First of all a div is not a button. I mean you could maybe do styling to make it look like a button, but why not just use:

```
<button type="button"> Add </button>
```

Also, you could just use onclick instead of defining that click event. I find this usually cleaner:

```
<button type="button" onclick="the_function();"> Add </button>
```

And then in your javascript define the function:

```
function the_function()
{
    var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
    $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
});
```

However, you are better off putting an id on the input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="check-list-input" name="checkListItem"/>
```

Obviously you don't need to use that naming convention. After doing that then you can revise that function to:

```
function the_function()
{
    var toAdd = $('#check-list-input').val();
    $('.list').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
});
```

But yet this still isn't as good as it should be. The list should also be an id not a class. If you had more than one list on the page, it would cause problems. Instead do this:

```
<div class="list" id="list-div"></div>
```

And then you can revise your function to:

```
function the_function()
{
    var toAdd = $('#check-list-input').val();
    $('#list-div').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
});
```

So the end result should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>To Do</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" id="check-list-input" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <button type="button" onclick="the_function();"> Add </button>
        <br/>
        <div class="list" id="list-div"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and for your jQuery (no need for document ready anymore, just be sure to include the javascript file or snippet before the html):

```
function the_function()
{
    var toAdd = $('#check-list-input').val();
    $('#list-div').append("<div class='item'>" + toAdd + "</div>");
});
```

I didn't test this yet, but I hope it works for you.